# Representing $i$ with divergent series

Tags: complex-analysis, computer-science, divergent-series

### Train of thought

In computer science, for representing signed integers, we can use the *two's complement* representation, so that $11111111_{(2)} = -1$ over 8 bits with $x_{(2)}$ denoting binary representation. This is used because $11111111_{(2)} + 00000001_{(2)} = 00000000_{(2)}$ (the overflowed 1 go to the non-existing ninth bit).

This made me think a bit about the mathematical aspect of this relation.
Given the divergent series (representing an infinity of ones in base 2):
$$S = \sum_{i=0}^\infty2^i$$
If we wanted to assign it a constant value, one can find that:
$$2\times S = \sum_{i=0}^\infty2^{i+1} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty2^i = S - 2^0$$
$$S = -1$$
Which is the result used in computer science. So, in a way, with only natural positive numbers, we get negative numbers.

### The question

Is there a way to **construct a divergent series** with elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that with a specific summation method, the **result would be a imaginary number**? If not, prove it.

Comment: What you are doing is reminiscent of [2-adic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number).

Comment: this is highly non probable. Because $\Bbb C$ has an automorphism (the conjugaison), and a certain summation process should choose between $i$ and $-i$, which you can't do with real numbers only.

Comment: Relevant: [complex base systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_base_systems)

Comment: The powerseries for $ \sqrt{1-2x} = 1 - x - 1/2 x^2 - 1/2 x^3 - 5/8 x^4 - 7/8 x^5 - 21/16 x^6 - 33/16 x^7 - 429/128 x^8  + O(x^9) $ evaluated at $x=1$ ? It is divergent and "represents" the imaginary unit...